# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 619: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, nltk

I've encountered the notorious `UnicodeEncodeError`. I've researched a lot about this error before posting this here, there are apparently multiple versions of this error.

Here's my code:

```
import nltk,re,pprint
import geograpy
import codecs
from nameparser.parser import HumanName

text_file = codecs.open('H:/Study and Work/Marciano Asstship/Work/Incident_cards_data/2.Text Extracted/Boxes 1 - 21/Boxes 8 thru 21-TULE LAKE/Box9-TULE LAKE/box9.txt',encoding = 'utf-8')
text_data = text_file.read()

places = geograpy.get_place_context(text_data)
print places
```

and  here's the error:

```
log.debug('%s on %s' % (e, url))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 619: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What makes your situation radically different from the _numerous_ other answers to this exact question?  In what way(s) do those other solutions fail to solve your problem?

Comment: In all the other situations, encoding using 'utf-8' solves the problem. In my situation, if I encode using utf-8 then I get the above error, if I decode using utf-8, I get the UnicodeDecodeError. I have also tried several other encodings but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` or `url` is a Unicode string, which makes the resulting string passed to `log.debug` a Unicode string.  Examples:

```
>>> '%s %s' % ('abc','def')
'abc def'
>>> '%s %s' % (u'abc','def')
u'abc def'
>>> '%s %s' % ('abc',u'def')
u'abc def'
>>> '%s %s' % (u'abc',u'def')
u'abc def'
```

Likely `log.debug` doesn't expect Unicode strings, so Python 2 implicitly converts it to a byte string using the default `ascii` codec.  The Unicode string generated isn't ASCII-compatible, hence `UnicodeEncodeError`.